# Extended desktop (dual widescreen monitors)

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I upgraded recently to Ubuntu 11.10 from 10.04.  I have twin Samsung 19" Syncmasters that run natively on 1680x1050, one to the DVI1 and one to the VGA1 output of my fixed dual-head integrated Intel graphics card (82G33/G31).  In I was able to use xrandr in 10.04 to set my desktop size to twice 1680x1050 (3360x1050) and put my DVI output to the right of the VGA output.  Now the best I can do is mirror 1680x1050, which isn't very helpful.

I've read somewhere that Intel drivers now don't support resolutions larger than 2048x2048 in either dimension.  Is there any way to get around this and get back to my initial set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a limitation of compositing. It affects Unity 3D and (I think) Gnome Shell. However, if you change to a different environment such as Unity 2D or Gnome Classic, that limitation should disappear.

When you log in, you can click the gear icon next to your name and choose Unity 2D. To get Gnome Classic, you have to install `gnome-shell`.

I presume that other interfaces such as Xfce (Xubuntu) or Lxde (Lubuntu) should work, as well.

Comment: thanks!  i tried using unity 2d before but the sidebar launcher and top menu bar weren't coming up b/c of my old .compiz/.config settings (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859141).  now i'm logging into unity 2d by default.  As a side question, can I still run compiz with unity 2d?

Comment: @JohnS: Yes, although you'll have to disable the Unity plugin to keep from getting duplicate panels and launchers. However, Compiz is what's causing your problem, so running it will bring it back.